# How to format data to be used by a classifier in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a dataset that I need to run through a classify function to find a specific result. I am having difficulty getting the classifier to work as wolfram is telling me that the data is not in the right format. Any clues on what I can do?

Comment: Imagine you don't know everything about your problem. Imagine you know some Mathematica and someone asks "why is my classifier data in the wrong format", but doesn't give you any hint what their data looks like or what their code looks like. How much would you be able to help them without that information. Then think about editing your question so that someone reading your question would likely be able to tell you what to try.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "Any clues on what I can do?" Yes, use the right format as documented.